# How to test if a character in a string is a number?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that tests the strength of a password. Right now, everything else works, however the numbers doesn't. I can't test whether a string is a number without it not returning the last print statement. I probably haven't explained it well, but how can I make it so that it tests if a characer in a string is a number?

```
    error_list = ['']
    errors = ''
    password = str(input('Enter in your password to test: '))

    for char in password:
        if type(char) == int:
            safe_unsafe.append('y')
        else:
            safe_unsafe.append('n')
    if 'y' in safe_unsafe:
        pass
    else:
        errors = errors + 'No instance of a number was found.\n'
        error_list.append('number')
        safe_unsafe.clear()
    print(errors)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `isdigit()` API
https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit

Example

```
str = "1"
str.isdigit() #this return True

"a".isdigit() #return False
```

Updates in your code

```
error_list = ['']
    errors = ''
    password = str(input('Enter in your password to test: '))

    for char in password:
        if char.isdigit():  #changed line
            safe_unsafe.append('y')
        else:
            safe_unsafe.append('n')
    if 'y' in safe_unsafe:
        pass
    else:
        errors = errors + 'No instance of a number was found.\n'
        error_list.append('number')
        safe_unsafe.clear()
    print(errors)
```